# Change application descriptor at runtime in flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3

I have run into two issues working on flex 3 currently:

1. Is it possible to change  field at runtime or atleast set values through actionscript during the initialization(or at runtime)?
2. Right now I don't use flex sdk or the builder, how should I access native application, if I import flash.desktop.nativeapplication it says not found when I compile.

Comment: Application Descriptors are used for AIR apps as I understood it.  They area compile time values that cannot be changed at runtime.  What value do you want to change?  How cna you use Flex 3 without using the Flex SDK?  You need to provide a lot more details on what you're trying to do and how you're doing it and what the problems are.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear, I do use the sdk, I meant the builder(I'm super new to flex). What I'm doing is package a flex application into an android apk, and I wrote my own descriptor file for this. The original flex application however, is browser based(accessed on a server at 8080) I have the server address hardcoded, along with a username/pass but I want this to be based on user input, not necessarily at runtime, but atleast when the application starts.  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I don't understand where in an Application Descriptor file you are specifying a server.  However, if your code is accessing a server there are ways to change that at runtime; but you haven't shared enough specifics for us to direct you.  On another note; I would not expect a browser based Flex 3 app to work very well on a mobile device without extensive changes.